# Open a new page when reload/refresh or back is done

Tags: javascript, html

If I refresh/reload a page, then how can I navigate to a different page.

If I press back button or do back, then how can I navigate to a different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onunload` method on `window`

your `js` would be

```
window.onunload=function(){
window.location.href="another page URL";
}
```